# Wait for execution to complete before executing again

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to prevent my click handler from executing multiple times, however it is not working as expected. Is my approach in the right direction? I want this handler to get executed when user clicks on button just once. This handler can get executed again of course (after the execution has completed).

```js
var init = false,
    i = 1;

$('button').on('click', function() {
  if (init) {
    return;
  }

  init = true;

  (function() {
    // this for loop is for example purposes, just to have something running
    for (var i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
      $('.text').append(i)
    }
    init = false;
  }());

  $('.counter').html(i);
  i++
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Button</button>
<div class="text"></div>
<div class="counter"></div>
```

Comment: How you got to know it's executed twice? According to your script the program is executing only once.

Comment: During execution the UI is blocked anyway, so the button is not clickable.

Comment: I've updated the code snippet. You can see that the counter is increasing, even though the execution hasn't completed. Test it buy clicking multiple times in quick succession @SumanBogati

Comment: what about `var i=0;
$('button').on('click', function() {
 if(i == 0 || i >= 5000){
  for (; i < 5000; i++) {
   $('.text').append(i+"<br />")
  }
 }
 });
})`

Comment: Is `for` loop actual process to be executed , or for example purposes ? Is requirement for UI to not be blocked during `for` loop processing ? What is purpose of appending `i` 4999 times to `.text` element ?

Comment: The `for` loop is for example purposes (I should have mentioned that). The requirement is for the UI __to__ be blocked while the loop processes @guest271314

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After figuring out that the UI was being blocked, I looked into solutions to 'chunking' the loop into smaller loops, allowing the UI to become unblocked and other functions to be executed.

**Chunked for loop**

```
function loop(arr, fn, before, callback) {
    let index = 0,
        step = 50,
        stepTotal = step;

    before();

    (function chunk() {
        while(index < arr.length && index < stepTotal) {
            fn(arr[index], index);
            index++;
        }

        if (index < arr.length) {
            stepTotal+=step;
            setTimeout(chunk, 0);
        } else {
            callback();
        }
    })()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `button` property `disabled` to `true` at beginning of `init` ,  using `.hide()` , `.delay()` , `.show()` , setting `disabled` property to `false`

```js
var count = 1,
  max = 5000,
  init = function() {
    $(this).prop("disabled", true)
    .off("click.count");
    $(".counter").html(count);
    count++;
    $(this).hide(0, function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        $(".text").append(i);
      }
    }).delay(max / 2).show(function() {
      $(this).prop("disabled", false)
      .on("click.count", init)
    })
  };

$("button").on("click.count", init);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<button id="button">Button</button>
<div class="text"></div>
<div class="counter"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here try this solution.

At first we register click handler to button :

```
$('button').on('click', runThis );
```

And here the runThis() handler function :

```
function runThis() {
  // register off click handler on button
  $('button').off('click');    
  // loop over i
  for (var i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
    $('.text').append('<br/>' + i);        
  }
  // if execution finish
  if (i == 2000) {
    // register back handler
    addBack();
  }
}
```

And here we on back the click handler on button :

```
function addBack() {
   $('button').on('click', runThis );
}
```

Comment: `i` is outside of `for` loop at `if (i == 2000)` ?

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer this, however the `for` loop in my question is for example purposes only

Comment: @guest271314 though i can be accessed from outside since block not have local scoping

Comment: Then it just an illustration for you how to off/on event handler. Another way to use deferred promised for UI animation purpose.